# file path validation using protractor

Tags: protractor, automated-tests, filepath

```
var fs = require('fs');
browser.sleep(1000);
expect(fs.existsSync(browser.params.configname.DOWNLOAD_PATH + 
browser.params.variablesName.IMAGE_FILES[1])).toBe(true);
```

`fs.existsSync()` function returning false sometimes.

(I have verified the path and it is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

`browser.sleep(1000)` is not a reliable way of waiting for something, you should `wait` on a condition to fulfill instead.  Something like the below:

```
browser.wait(() => {
    console.log('waiting for file to exist');
    return fs.existsSync(file);
}).then(() => {
    console.log('file exists');
    // do something
});
```